# Ember-Build - How config for local host running?

Tags: ember.js

I require to run my ember application after I do the `ember build -prod` for testing purpose. I am using `xaamp` local server. But I am not able to run my app.

I am getting the following errors:

```
localhost/:13 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/vendor-67b1c7f5f2eb1b051649864903c92044.css 
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/rdc-ui-servicerequest-csd-9635212553537ffc063efb35021419f0.css 
Navigated to http://localhost:8080/Ember/
localhost/:22 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/rdc-ui-servicerequest-csd-718fc0f8bad1138cf9007d42e5ab2fff.js 
localhost/:21 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/vendor-0e6b914827a8308d459cf96ddc1a551e.js 
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/rdc-ui-servicerequest-csd-9635212553537ffc063efb35021419f0.css 
localhost/:13 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/vendor-67b1c7f5f2eb1b051649864903c92044.css 
localhost/:22 GET http://localhost:8080/assets/rdc-ui-servicerequest-csd-718fc0f8bad1138cf9007d42e5ab2fff.js
```

How to fix this? any how can i run my build in localhost of my system. any one please help me to configure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running `ember build`?  are you packaging the output from the build in a folder your web server is serving?

Comment: Yes, I do the same